# get number of google search results

Tags: java, search

I searched a lot to retrieve the number of search results in google using java, but nothing worked.
I have tried Google Custom Search API aswell.
I don't want the title/url of results, just number of total results found.
Can some one please guide me?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34808872/363573

Answer (score 13):

By using the Custom Search API, you're on the right way.

There's a `totalResults` key in the [response JSON](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#WorkingResults) that you get from your query. Just grab it's value and you're done.

If you want your JSON to only contain that value, add the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#st_params) parameter to your query like that:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&cx={YOUR_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}
    &q={YOUR_SEARCH_STRING}&alt=json&fields=queries(request(totalResults))
```

Comment: Here is a solution not relying on Custom Search API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34808872/363573

Comment: Note that the Custom Search API only allows you 100 free searches a day (and I imagine the other commented solution will throttle you similarly).

Comment: @Stephan Google may start banning your queries after couple of searches as they have better protection system against bots.