# How to get #resultStats from Google using Jsoup

Tags: android, android-studio, jsoup

I am trying to get the number of articles that Google shows us:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgBMd.png) is a Google search of `jeb bush barack obama`, and it shows the number that I need, which is the `10,200,000` articles

How can I use Jsoup and any of its components to grab that number?

I tried: 
      `Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements description = document.select("div#resultStats");
desc = description.attr("content");`

Note: I am using Android Studio and I want to save the result into a matrix.

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOP01.png) is what I see for the number of articles on the HTML source code.

Comment: The downloaded document doesn't have resultStats (at least in testing at http://try.jsoup.org). Try using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11569731/1048340

Comment: Try using desc = description.text()

Comment: @Jared, Google search API does not exist anymore AFAIK, so that will not work.

Comment: It's deprecated but still works. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=jeb%20bush%20barack%20obama Looks like the "resultStats" are different though. :\

Comment: @JaredRummler It doesn't because the document contains some Javascript in charge of building the final HTML code.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you may be getting some optimized javascript code (for modern browsers) that need to be run to see actual results stats. Instead, change your user agent string (for a oldest browser UA string) and the url like in the code below:

#### DEMO

http://try.jsoup.org/~iYErM3BgfjILVJZshDMkAd-XQCk

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=jeb+bush+barack+obama";

Document document = Jsoup //
                   .connect(url) //
                   .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)") //
                   .get();

Element divResultStats = document.select("div#resultStats").first();
if (divResultStats==null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find results stats.");
}

System.out.println(divResultStats.text());
```

#### OUTPUT (as of this writing...)

```
About 10,500,000 results
```

**Tested on Jsoup 1.8.3**

More UA Strings: http://www.useragentstring.com/