Is there an efficient way to access the number of results returned by a search engine to a particular query using Python?
I have a large dataset (around 40,000) of entities in a .csv file and want to store their popularity by storing the number of search results they return when searched up. So, I'm trying to get it done fast and reliably. It doesn't have to be really accurate, but it's the best way I figured to get a good gauge of its public importance. I'm solving this using Python 3.X
Edit: The dataset is of known Company software vulnerabilities in the CVE, so it comprises of data like "Lenovo EZ Media", "Sylius", "Oracle Corporation Hyperion Infrastructure Technology", etc. Hence, I found the search result gauge to be the best, though I am grateful to suggestions of other ways to measure a Company/Products Exposure to the public
I've tried using beautiful soup, but it doesn't always return a value. In fact if I search up something not really popular, it'll show- value not present, but then if I search it up on my actual browser and then run the program, it'll then give an output. Which is not really reliable. I found out it happens because of some JavaScript dynamic loading of the page.
import requests
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def get_search_results_count(query):
    search_url = f"https://www.bing.com/search?q={query}"

    response = requests.get(search_url, verify=False)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    count_element = soup.find("span", class_="sb_count")

    if count_element:
        count_text = count_element.text.strip()
        return count_text
    else:
        return "Search results count not found"

search_query = "cheese"
result_count = get_search_results_count(search_query)
print(result_count)
numeric_part = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, result_count))
print(numeric_part)

So then as a result, I tried using Selenium, but it takes too much time. Plus, it actually opens up the search engine on my computer, and then closes it, so it seems to be pretty inefficient.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def get_search_results_count(query):
    driver = webdriver.Edge()

    try:
        # Construct the search URL
        search_url = f"https://www.bing.com/search?q={query}"
        driver.get(search_url)

        count_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sb_count")
        count_text = count_element.text.strip()
        return count_text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return "Search results count not found"
    finally:
        driver.quit()


search_query = input("Enter the Company and Product name as one...:\n")
result_count = get_search_results_count(search_query)
print(result_count)
numeric_part = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, result_count))
search_results = numeric_part


I really don't know what to do. I don't want anything to do with the actual search results, I just want to know the amount which are returned. I once saw someone suggest the Google search API, but it doesn't seem relatable to my problem of just wanting the result number, and it seems to be too complex for me to figure out, if someone could help me out with that, that would be great.

Selenium is a great Python tool for webscraping (I'd use it over requests). What did you mean it takes too much time?

If you don't want it to open up a browser, you can use it in headless mode

@WilliamBakerMorrison I mean that per query, it takes at least 5 seconds to return a result, and when i try it in headless mode, I keep getting the error 'WebDriver.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path''

Well that's a separate error. As stated you need to provide the path of the Driver executable (either firefox/chrome driver)

A web-scraping approach would probably be infeasible for this task given the size of your dataset, and you can do better than just number of search results for a gauge of public importance. One simple way you might do this is by using Google Trends. In python, you can use the pytrends module, and to extract some sort of index of popularity akin to number of search results, you might do something like this:
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=0, timeout=None)
keywords = ["dataset"]
pytrends.build_payload(keywords, timeframe='2015-01-01 2024-01-01')

This still has the problem of being rate-limited as it is an unofficial API, but since you are not actually performing the search, and are instead querying the data, it is likely to perform better than your current solution.

Thank you! But as you mentioned, the fact that it's rate limited does cause a problem for large data. I'm sorry that I wasn't more specific with my data before, but it's a data set of known Company web Vulnerabilities, and I wanted to gauge how much a product like Lenovo EZ Media is known by the public. pytrends is not specific enough for that.

The Google Custom Search API has a totalResults key in the response, and this would include less popular terms that show as 0 on Google Trends. Unfortunately, the Custom Search API only allows 100 free searches per day. The following answer may help you find a solution without this API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401466/how-to-get-resultstats-from-google-using-jsoup/34808872#34808872.
