# Extract Google Search Engine Result

Tags: python, google-chrome

I would like to scrap/extract the number of results given by Google Search Engine for a given word with Python, but I can't with Beautifulsoup and Request library.
If anyone can help me out that would be great.

A print screen is attached to better explain the number I want to extract.

[Google Search Engine Result 'decoration'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTXFY.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the search page, you can see that the value is inside a div with an id.
[image: inspect result]

That is good for your purpose since ids uniquely identify elements within the page. To find out how to get an element by its id you just need to make a google search ([first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136267/beautiful-soup-and-extracting-a-div-and-its-contents-by-id)), and then you can get the text from the "text" property. You will also need to parse the text, to only extract the number.

Edit:
Looks like, without providing a user agent, the google API will not return the full page. If you send the "User-Agent" header with the value from your browser, it should work. A quick way to check yourself is to run the request in Postman, where you can just search if the result has what you need.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
            'https://www.google.com/search?q=f', headers={ "user-agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'}).text, features="html.parser")

text = html.body.find('div', attrs={'id': 'result-stats'}).text

print(text)
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that Google provides endpoints exactly for this kind of purpose. Here's another question referring to the same problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569381/get-number-of-google-search-results)).

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I did what you said, but the result is none or error with "test" or "string".
This is what I do works well on other sites but not on Google.

Comment: @HervéRamboasalama I added a working sample

Comment: Thank you very much.
Mine missing a lot of information.